# Connecting to a server using android and Java sockets with needed permission from user

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, server

I want to connect to a server using java but the problem is that it seems nothing is working. I know this question has been asked a lot of time but non of them seem to provide a solution for this problem.

My server code:

```
//SERVER
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
Socket s1 = serverSocket.accept();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(s1.getOutputStream());
ps.println("text");
```

---

My client code:

```
//CLIENT
Socket s2 = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(s2.getInputStream()));
String input = br.readLine();
```

---

I have added the permission tag in the android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

What am I doing wrong. I'm not new to Java Sockets but I am new to the world of android. Do I need to run my network code in a seperate thread or what else solves my problem?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**I have checked the logs and console and no exception have been caught.

Comment: No exceptions caught?

Comment: @YoungMillie I have checked and no exceptions have been caught.

Comment: Is the server running in a different application or within the same as the client?

Comment: hum that's weird, you shouldn't be able to run network operations on the UI thread, an exception should be thrown

Comment: can you post the full android code?

Comment: What exactly does your app do?  There may be a better way to communicate rather than creating sockets by hand.

Comment: @lelloman how should I do this then?

Comment: @GaryBak It's a remote system where I can retrieve data by sending a command to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're not getting any exception on the android client this means that you're not actually opening the socket, if you do open it on the UI thread you get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. so i suspect that piece of code you posted is not being executed at all.
regarding how to do it on android it depends, if it's a short operation you can use an `AsyncTask`. keep in mind that one `AsyncTask` does not equals one `Thread`, they get queued up. if you need to keep the connection alive you can use a Thread. check out [this example](https://github.com/lelloman/android-audiostreamlistener/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/lelloman/audiostreamlistener/threading/NetworkPingBroadcaster.java) for AsyncTask and [this other one](https://github.com/lelloman/android-audiostreamlistener/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/lelloman/audiostreamlistener/threading/AudioClient.java) for Thread. they use `DatagramSocket` but the idea it's the same

Comment: Thanks mate for the solution. The socket should stay open so I think I'm going to use a thread. But I'm definitely going the check the AsyncTask.

Comment: you're welcome but again, be careful with AsynkTask because they are not meant to replace Threads in android but only used for short operations